# Is raw video output from android camera possible?

Tags: android, video, camera

I'm pretty much new at this, so here is my newbie question.

Is there any way to capture a video (or series of images as a workaround) from built-in camera in RAW_Sensor or RAW_Private format and with stable and greater or equal to 24 framerate? If there is a way, then how?﻿ If there is not, then why?

Comment: See if this helps you in any way: https://nidesai.wordpress.com/2013/09/22/android-camera-capturing-raw-video-frames/

Comment: No. It is not, what I'm looking for. I need raw data from camera sensor in raw formats (as in raw_sensor or raw_private described here [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html))